# Catastrophic backtracking -- regex causing my Python3 program to hang

Tags: python-3.x, regex

The following regex to capture email is causing catastrophic backtracking:

```
[a-z0-9&+^_~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9&+^_~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z]{2,}
```

This regex is so simple I'm not seeing a problem or how I could rewrite it so it doesn't cause issues.

Is there a way in Python3 to terminate a regex findall by time?

Comment: A large text file -- it'd be hard to post it here.

Comment: You have to post some examples that can reproduce your problem

Comment: You can just use `r'\b[a-z0-9_][a-z0-9&+^_~-]*(?:\.[a-z0-9&+^_~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z]{2,}'`

Comment: Do I need a raw string if I'm using Python3?

Comment: It seems like this is the part that causing me problems: (?:\.[a-z0-9&+^_~-]+)*